# refund function in smart contract

Tags: contract-development, address.transfer, gas-refund

I am looking to add a Refund function in my smart contract.
Like If User A deposited 1 ETH in the contract, and uses refund function, he gets 1 ETH - Gas Fee back.

I can do the **transfer(address.balance-fee)** however the issue is there can be multiple depositors.
How can I make sure they only get the amount they deposited.

Comment: Please show your code, so that any answer here can refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to keep track of who deposited and how much. It can be as simple as `mapping(address => uint)` - remember also that probably a user can make multiple deposits from the same address so you need to increase that value and not overwrite.

You can modify the mapping entries simply with something like this (assuming `mymap` is the mapping: `mymap[msg.sender] += msg.value`.

Depending on how you are planning to pay the deposits back you maybe need another data structure to store the addresses (an array), if you want to push the deposits. But if users can pull the deposits (call something like `giveMeMyDepositBack`) then you don't need a separate data structure and you can simply send back the deposit minus fee.

Comment: Is there any possibility of you providing me this as a code? I am not sure how mapping works.

Comment: Added a bit of code